# jQuery append issue in wrong order

Tags: jquery, append

```
if (cinemaValue == "maxima") {
     if (dayValue=="mon" || dayValue=="tue" || dayValue=="wed" || dayValue=="thu" || dayValue=="fri") {
         var timeByDay = {"na":"--- Select a time ---", 6:"6pm", 9:"9pm"};
     } else if (dayValue=="sat" || dayValue=="sun") {
         var timeByDay = {"na":"--- Select a time ---", 3:"3pm",6:"6pm", 9:"9pm"};
    }
}
$.each(timeByDay, function(value, text){
    $("#time").append(new Option(text, value));
})
```

I am trying to append timeByDay into a drop down list which is empty. I expected to have a data in dropdown list with order (--- select a time ---, 6pm, 9pm). However, in my result, --- select a time --- always appear as a last child in the list, like (6pm, 9pm, --- select a time ---).

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: `timeByDay` is an object which does not guarantee the order of keys - create `timeByDay` as an array

Comment: Try 0 or 1 instead of `na` may be this causes the sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array. Currently you are using an object which does not guarantee the order of keys.

Change you object like

```
 var timeByDay = [{
     text: "--- Select a time ---",
     value: "na"
 }, {
     text: "6pm",
     value: "6"
 }];
```

And then use it to populate select.

```
$.each(timeByDay, function(index, item){
   $("#time").append(new Option(item.text, item.value));
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ptjvaau2/)